# Integrating $\frac{1}{u}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Say I have $\int_{}{}\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{u + 1}du$

Why is $\frac{1}{2}\ln(u + 1) \neq \frac{1}{2}\ln(2u + 2)$?

Assuming I did this:

$$\int_{}{}\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{u + 1}\ du = \int_{}{}\frac{1}{2u + 2}\ du$$

Comment: Do you know that $\ln(a\cdot b)=\ln a+\ln b$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are forgetting the constant for an indefinite integral.

Note that

$$\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{du}{u+1} = \frac{1}{2} \ln (u+1) + C,$$

and

$$\frac{1}{2} \ln(2u+2) = \frac{1}{2} \ln (u+1 ) + \frac{\ln 2}{2}.$$

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot + C. My professor's answer is the former + C. So my answer, the latter form + C is equivalent because the two only differ by some constant C?

Comment: @darylnak: That is correct. $\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{du}{u+1} = \frac{1}{2} \ln(u+1) +C$ and  $\int \frac{du}{2u+2} = \frac{1}{2} \ln(2u+2) +D$ are both correct and not inconsistent since they can differ by a constant.  Both forms are equivalent antiderivatives.

Comment: Are you assuming that $u+1>0$, or should it be $\ln|u+1|$?

Comment: The argument is to address the OP's confusion about why two forms that differ by a constant are equivalent antiderivatives. We could have stated that the domain of the function $ u \mapsto 1/(1+u)$ is $(-1, \infty)$ without any material impact.  Otherwise we use $\ln|u+1|$ as you suggest.